# How to check if a folder has any tab delimited file in it?

Tags: bash

I am trying to search for all the tab delimited file in one folder, and if found any then I need to transfer all of them to a another folder using bash.

In my code, I am currently trying to find all files, but somehow it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
>nul 2>nul dir /a-d "folderName\*" && (echo Files exist) || (echo No file found)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: None of this looks very much like Bash. Are you trying to write a script for Windows `cmd` actually?

Comment: No, I want this done in bash only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a simple move (or copy -- replace `mv` with `cp`) of files, @tripleee's answer is sufficient. To recursively search for files and run a command on each, `find` comes in handy.

Example:

```
find <src> -type f -name '*.tsv' -exec cp {} <dst> \;
```

Where `<src>` is the directory to copy *from*, and `<dst>` is the directory to copy *to*. Note that this searches recursively, so any files with duplicate names will cause overwrites. You can pass `-i` to `cp` to have it prompt before overwriting:

```
find <src> -type f -name '*.tsv' -exec cp -i {} <dst> \;
```

Explained:

```
find <src> -type f -name '*.tsv' -exec cp -i {} <dst> \;
^    ^     ^     ^ ^     ^       ^     ^  ^  ^  ^     ^^
|    |     |     | |     |       |     |  |  |  |     ||
|    |     |     | |     |       |     |  |  |  |     | --- terminator
|    |     |     | |     |       |     |  |  |  |      --- escape for terminator
|    |     |     | |     |       |     |  |  |   --- destination directory
|    |     |     | |     |       |     |  |   --- the path of each file found
|    |     |     | |     |       |     |   --- prompt before overwriting
|    |     |     | |     |       |      --- the copy command
|    |     |     | |     |        --- flag for executing a command (cp in this case)
|    |     |     | |      --- pattern of files to match
|    |     |     |  --- flag for specifying file name pattern
|    |     |      --- 'f' for a regular file (as opposed to e.g. 'd' for directory)
|    |      --- flag for specifying the file type
|     --- location to search
 --- the find command, useful for searching for files
```

To get a feel for what happens without actually having `find` run the real command, you can prefix it with `echo` to just print each command instead of running it:

```
find <src> -type f -name '*.tsv' -exec echo cp -i {} <dst> \;
```

Comment: What is `{}` for? Do I need to mention path for each found everytime inside the curly braces then?

Comment: `find` replaces the `{}` with the path to each file. If you had a file `./foo.tsv` and destination `../bar/`, `find` would run `cp -i ./foo.tsv ../bar/`.

Comment: Yes. `{}` is special syntax that `find` understands. Only replace `<src>` and `<dst>` with the source and destination directories.

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt has very little valid Bash script in it.

```
mv foldername/*.tsv otherfolder/
```

There will be an error message if there are no matching files.

Comment: ehm...  it is valid bash, actually.

Comment: @LjmDullaart The `dir /a-d`, the `nul` redirect, and the backslash as folder separator looks very much like Windows, though nothing *per se* forbids you from having a DOS utility and a regular file named `nul`. The parentheses are of course merely superflouous. Not sure if Window does something useful with a wildcard inside double quotes; in Bash it's certainly just a literal asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

"it is not working". That means very little on stackoverflow.

Let's first examine what you've done:

```
>nul 2>nul dir /a-d "folderName\*"
```

So, you're doing a `dir` (most Linux users would use `ls`, but soit) on

- /a-d
- everything under folderName

and the output is in the file `nul`. For debugging purposes, it would be good to see what is in `nul` (do `cat nul`). I would bet it is something like:

```
dir: cannot access '/a-d': No such file or directory
dir: cannot access 'folderName\*': No such file or directory
```

That means that `dir` exits with an error.  So, `echo No file found` will be executed.

This means that  your output is probably

```
No file found
```

Which is exactly as expected.

In your code, you said you want to find all files. That means you want the output of

```
ls folderName
```

or

```
find folderName
```

if you want to do things recursively. Because `find` has been explained above by jsageryd, I won't elaborate on that.

If you just want to look in that specific directory, you might do:

```
if dir folderName/*.tsv > nul 2>nul ; then
    echo "Files exist"
else
    echo "No file found"
fi
```

and go from there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I realized my mistake after posting the question on here and since I am new to Linux, and I found the code I was working on another question where it did not mention that the code was for CMD and not bash.